# .htaccess deny access if user agent is not like this but exclude specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to deny access to my site from all user_agents, expect  U_AGENT1 & U_AGENT2  but exclude file.php so file.php can be viewed with any user agent

i have tried this code , it block the access for other user agent but also for file.php so i cant exclude it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file\.php$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(U_AGENT1 |U_AGENT12)
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: maybe `expr` help you `RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ /U_AGENT1|U_AGENT12/i"`

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located? Where is `file.php` located? The directives as posted should already do as you require providing both the `.htaccess` and `file.php` files are located in the document root. When you request `/file.php` the first condition fails and the rule is not processed, allowing unrestricted access to `/file.php`.

Comment: @Deadooshka That's no different to the _condition_ in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(U_AGENT1 |U_AGENT12)
RewriteRule !^(file\.php)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to formulate this into a complete answer as it doesn't make sense by itself (in the context of your question). If you simply replace the `RewriteRule` in the question with this then it wouldn't make any difference (assuming `file.php` and `.htaccess` are both located in the document root).